realizar keydown.click() en un plugin select2
tengo un buscador que al momento de hacer click con el mouse este se abre y toma focus para escribir una descripción o poder escanear un código de barra.
El problema es que tengo que hacerlo ahora presionando la tecla F3 pero no he podido hacerlo
Tengo un componente que en su interior tiene un fragmento con el código siguiente, el 'F2', 'Escape', 'ArrowRight' y 'ArrowLeft' funcionan, pero el F3 no lo hace.
 @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event.key);

    switch (event.key) {
      case 'F3':
        event.preventDefault();
        this.clickFnClass('form-control');
        break;
      case 'F2':
        event.preventDefault();
        this.clickFnId('pagarId');
        break;
      case 'Escape':
        event.preventDefault();
        this.clickFnId('cancelarId');
        break;
      case 'ArrowRight':
        event.preventDefault();
        this.clickFnClass('btn btn-sm btn-success brd');
        break;
      case 'ArrowLeft':
        event.preventDefault();
        this.clickFnClass('btn btn-sm btn-danger bri');
        break;
    }
  }

  clickFnId(idEtiqueta: string) {
    const buttonElement = document.getElementById(idEtiqueta)
    
    if (buttonElement) {
       buttonElement.click();
    }
  }

  clickFnClass(nombreClase: string) {
    const buttonElement = document.getElementsByClassName(nombreClase)
    if (buttonElement.length > 0) {
      const lastElementIndex = buttonElement.length - 1;
      const lastElement = buttonElement[lastElementIndex];
      (lastElement as HTMLElement).click(); 
    }
  }

aqui dejo el fragmento del select2
 <div class="col-12 sticky-div">
      <app-pos-buscador
         [tipoPrecio]="tipoPrecio"
         (onProductoPromocion)="nuevoProductoEnTabla($event)"
      ></app-pos-buscador>
   </div> 

este es mi selector.html
<select2
  class="form-control mb-3"
  [data]="elementosConsolida"
  [value]="valueConsolida"
  customSearchEnabled
  placeholder="Buscar o escanear productos"
  styleMode="noStyle"
  resultMaxHeight="170px"
  (search)="_search($event)"
  (update)="_update($event)"
  (close)="_close()"
></select2>

aca dejo el app-pos-buscador.ts de .html antes escrito.
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Select2Data } from 'ng-select2-component';
import { FuncionesBusqueda } from 'src/app/common/commonFunction';
import { ProductoSucursalResponse, PromocionResponse } from 'src/app/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pos-buscador',
  templateUrl: './pos-buscador.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pos-buscador.component.css'],
})
export class PosBuscadorComponent {
  private valueSearchMark: string = '';
  productos: ProductoSucursalResponse[] = [];
  promos: PromocionResponse[] = [];
  elementosConsolida: Select2Data = [];
  elementosConsolidaHash: Select2Data = [];
  valueConsolida: string = '';
  promociones: PromocionResponse[] = [];
  interval: any;
  enterInterval: any;
  @Input() tipoPrecio: number = 4;

  @Output() onProductoPromocion = new EventEmitter<ProductoSucursalResponse>();

  constructor(private common: FuncionesBusqueda) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.cargaProductosPromociones();
    }, 3000);
  }

  async cargaProductosPromociones() {
    this.elementosConsolidaHash = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([]));
    this.productos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ProductosOffline') + '');
    this.promos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('PromocionesOffline') + '');
    if (this.productos && this.productos.length > 0) {
      this.productos.forEach((prod) => {
        this.elementosConsolidaHash.push({
          value: `${
            prod.producto.codigoBarra1 ? prod.producto.codigoBarra1 : ''
          } - ${prod.producto.codigoBarra2 ? prod.producto.codigoBarra2 : ''}`,
          label: `${prod.producto.descripcion} | ${this.common.formatCurrency(
            this.common.extraerNumero(this.obtenerPrecioUnitario(prod))
          )}`,
          templateId: 'template1',
          id: `prod_${prod.producto.id}`,
        });
      });
    }

    if (this.promos && this.promos.length > 0) {
      this.promos.forEach((prom) => {
        this.elementosConsolidaHash.push({
          value: `${
            prom.codigoBarraPromocion ? prom.codigoBarraPromocion : ''
          }`,
          label: `${prom.nombrePromocion} | ${this.common.formatCurrency(
            this.common.extraerNumero(prom.precioBrutoPromocion)
          )}`,
          templateId: 'template1',
          id: `prom_${prom.id}`,
        });
      });
    }
  }

  obtenerPrecioUnitario(producto: ProductoSucursalResponse) {
    const precio = producto.sucursalPrecio.find(
      (x) => x.idTipoVenta == this.tipoPrecio
    );
    if (precio) return precio.precioBruto;
    else return 0;
  }

  _search(valor: any) {
    clearInterval(this.enterInterval);
    this.elementosConsolida = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([]));
    if (valor.search && valor.search.length > 2) {
      this.preSearch(valor.search);
      this.newSearch(valor);
    } else {
      this.elementosConsolida = [];
    }
  }

  preSearch(searchValue: string) {
    this.elementosConsolida = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([]));

    this.elementosConsolida = this.elementosConsolidaHash.filter(
      (option: any) => {
        const newSearchValue = isNaN(parseInt(searchValue))
          ? searchValue
          : parseInt(searchValue).toString();
        return (
          option.label.toUpperCase().includes(newSearchValue.toUpperCase()) ||
          option.value.toUpperCase().includes(newSearchValue.toUpperCase())
        );
      }
    );
  }

  newSearch(valor: any) {
    valor.filteredData(
      valor.data.filter((option: any) => {
        const searchValue = isNaN(parseInt(valor.search))
          ? valor.search
          : parseInt(valor.search).toString();
        return (
          option.label.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase()) ||
          option.value.toUpperCase().includes(searchValue.toUpperCase())
        );
      })
    );

    if (this.elementosConsolida.length === 1) {
      if (valor.data.length > 0) {
        const value = valor.data[0].value.split('-');
        if (valor.search == value[0].trim() || valor.search == value[1].trim())
          this.enterInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.pressEnter();
          }, 10);
      }
    }
  }

  pressEnter() {
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
      key: 'Enter',
      code: 'Enter',
      which: 13,
      keyCode: 13,
    });

    // dispatch the event on some DOM element
    const searchBar = document.getElementsByClassName(
      'select2-search__field'
    )[0] as HTMLElement;
    searchBar.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  _update(valor: any) {
    if (valor.options) {
      const preValor = valor.options[0].id.split('_');
      switch (preValor[0]) {
        case 'prod':
          const producto = this.productos.find(
            (x) => x.producto.id == preValor[1]
          );
          if (producto) {
            if (producto.sucursalPrecio.length > 0) {
              this.agregarProductoALaTabla(producto);
            } else {
              this.common.mostrarMensaje(
                'error',
                'Operacion Caja',
                'No existen precios relacionados con este producto'
              );
            }
          }
          break;
        case 'prom':
          const promocion = this.promos.find(
            (x) => x.id == preValor[1]
          ) as ProductoSucursalResponse;
          this.agregarProductoALaTabla(promocion);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      valor.component.toggleOpenAndClose();
    }
  }

  _close() {
    clearInterval(this.enterInterval);
    this.elementosConsolida = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([]));
  }

  agregarProductoALaTabla(producto: ProductoSucursalResponse) {
    this.onProductoPromocion.emit(producto);
  }
}

todo esto bajo angular.
desde ya gracias.

F1 (Help),
F3 (Search),
F5 (Refresh),
F6 (focus address bar),
F7 (caret browsing mode),
F11 (full screen mode), and
F12 (used by several add-ons, including Firebug)
Quizás no funcione porque ya existe una función asignada a esa tecla

event.preventDefault(); esto desacopla las acciones por defecto.
